# PHP Namespacing , Classes and Includes - when functions get resolved - why is the function not found

Tags: php, class, namespaces

In my project a plugin for Wordpress:

I have a public class declared in its own file

```
<?php
    namespace Foo;

      Class Bar{

        function doSomething(){
             include 'partials/display.php';
             do_display();
        }

      } 
?>
```

in the file `partials/display.php`

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

function do_display(){
        //output some html
}

?>
```

My dilemma is that I get a function not found error on the do_display() line in function doSomething

I have read about when a function's name is read into the internal memory, but in this case, I can see I am reading the function into memory before its called. So I can only assume it has something to do with namespacing

Comment: Try adding curly braces around the namespace.  `<?php namespace Foo { function do_display() { .. }};`  Also, you probably want `require_once()` not `include()`.

Comment: remove namespace Foo; from partials/display.php file

Comment: yeah I recognise I could use require v include I will try bracketing but given they are semantically equivalent I am not sure that explains the errror

Comment: Can you explain why removing the namespace might work

Comment: The other issue was that this was working fine in development but once we moved to production we got the error